# I can not get access to pointer to member. Why?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

Consider the following code:

```
template<class T, class F>           struct X {};
template<class T, class F, T F::* m> struct Y {};

struct Foo {
    int member;
    typedef X<int, Foo>               x_type; // works well
    typedef Y<int, Foo, &Foo::member> y_type; // ERROR
};

typedef Y<int, Foo, &Foo::member> y_type2; // OK
```

Why does compiler generate error? (VS2008)

---

**New**

I have posted this bug to [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=514710).

Comment: What compiler are you using? There are no errors with g++ 4.3.3.

Comment: What is the error returned by the compiler?

Comment: I cannot understand the declaration of "Y" template. Template parameters are either types or integral values. "T F::* m" is not a type, with which you can parametrize your template...

When you write "Y<int, Foo, &Foo::member>", the last parameter is not a type and not an integral value. It is a pointer to the member. So, I beleive, it must be rejected...

Comment: In Visual Studio 2008: *"'Foo::member' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator"* and on the same line: "'member' : undeclared identifier"

Comment: This definitely works in GCC: http://codepad.org/XR94oTOO.

Comment: You know, reading SadSido's comment, I believe he is right!  I wonder why GCC considers it legal.

Comment: @jkp: VS2008 obviously also considers it legal, just not as a part of the struct.

Comment: From 14.1: A non-type template parameter shall have one of the following types [...] pointer to member.

Comment: Careful roe, not all pointers are just integers.

Comment: @roe, no we cannot just bend the rules as we like. pointers and member pointers are what they are, and integers/integrals are what they are. Member pointers are not even pointers in C++. They are *member* pointers, which is a separate category of type.

Comment: I think the description of the error message indicates that they have thought about another thing, and just forgot to implement this case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac27ea0d%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @roe, but that's exactly the point. There are two categories: The language, and the implementation. Surely, a reference in the language might be a pointer in the implementation, and a pointer in the language might be an integer in the implementation. The rules however that say whether you are allowed to pass pointers to templates, or add pointers together refer to pointers - so if you say "T F::* is an integral value", you make a category error because you are crossing different meanings of the same word, and apply the wrong meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=514710)

Comment: That what I said (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802204/i-can-not-get-access-to-pointer-to-member-why/1802365#1802365)

Answer (score 7):

I think that it is related somehow with that Visual C++ don't know the size of pointer to member at that point. Check [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=338226) defect report for instance ([here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=332857) is another problem with pointer to member variable). I think that you found one more Visual C++ bug and it should be reported to connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: I coincide with the 'bug' theory.  I stumbled upon the same problem lately, and found - but don't remember where - that they didn't yet 'fully support' pointer-to-member template class arguments.

Comment: However, the compiler doesn't need to know the _size_, imho.

Comment: I mean that `sizeof(&Foo::member)` could be 1 or more depending on `Foo` declaration.

Comment: And it is may be (I'm not sure) important for Visual C++. It is just a theory.

Comment: Doesn't the `&` sign show that it's a _pointer_-to-member, then?

Comment: My idea is that it is bug in implementation. I don't know why it is there :)

Comment: Found the bug report: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249045.  Applies to VC6.0, they say...

Comment: Not relevant. This particular behavior occurs with VC++ with pointers to member **functions**. This example is data. The cause of the difference is that a pointer to method can point to a virtual function, but there is no virtual data.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem.  The support for pointer-to-member template arguments is still limited in VC++ (see [bug report](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249045)).

In my case I could work around it by using a template function i.s.o. a template class:

```
template< typename Class > struct CMemberDumper {
    Class& object;
    template< typename M > void visit_member( M C::*pm ) {
       std::cout << object.*pm;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your bug is not related to my problem. It works well without any compiler errors. I use VS2008.